# Get Keychain to remember an additional field

Tags: keychain

I regularly log on to a financial website using Google Chrome

This requires me to enter a `Account` number, a `password` and also an `Employer` number.
I store the `Account` and `password` in my Keychain, but have to enter the 8 digit `Employer` number each time.

Is there any way of getting Keychain to remember this additional number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible.

But you can use Chrome to remember your Account number, while the keychain can contain the Password + Employer information.

However, some website (specialty finical) do not offer to save log in credentials for security reason.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to force Keychain to store the additional field.

I use [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword) for things that Safari/Keychain refuse to remember.
You can manually add fields for sites such as banks [at your own risk] where credentials will not auto-save.

There's also [LastPass](https://lastpass.com), but I haven't tried that

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at 1Password in the past, but will give a try again.